# Component resets all attributes when a dynamic attribute is changed

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have a component that I pass some static and dynamic parameters. The component updates these static values during interaction. When dynamic parameters are updated by the implementing component, all the static parameters are reset. I would expect that the component retains the updated value.

[Ember Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/4b348bfbf73af4b53c35?openFiles=outer-component.template.hbs%2Capplication.template.hbs)

I have implemented a work around where those values are set only during init, but I am wondering if this is intended behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the ember-twiddle example… `showYield=false` the static value `false` is changed via an action after render. Then the update time action changes `time` in the parent context (controller) causing the component template to redraw (which seems to have the side effect of resetting the `showYield` back to `false`.)

Since `time` is changed and `time` is passed to component the component re-renders using `false`, even after `showYield` was set to `true` from an action handler. `{{#outer-component time=time showYield=false}}`

So initially showYield is false, when passed into the component, the component has an action which changes showYield in the context of the component. `false` is always false, it's static. So next `time` is changed on the outer context (that is passed into the component) and that is (re)passed back into he component template. Since the static value is also (re)passed back into the component it's effectively reset.

I don't think you want to mix the static value and dynamic values of the component. Perhaps define the default value for `showYield` as `false` in a property; and use that property instead of the static value `showYield=property`.

Comment: perhaps join https://ember-community-slackin.herokuapp.com to see what other developers think as well.

Comment: Thank you for directing me where to ask my question and how to ask the community.  This lead me to a better understanding of what is going on.

Comment: From the chat discussion… "one way of thinking about it is that static variables are your way of saying something is NOT variable"